# getting list of emails in an irregular hash

Tags: ruby

I have params hash which is a composed of hashes of hashes and sometimes, those hash has an email.  What's the best way to get all the emails?  The params may be deeper than 3 levels.  I've only reached as far as going through each of the params, but I can't figure out how to do a nested search

```
params = {
  :email => 'foo@bar.com', 
  :name => 'foo bar',
  '0' => {
    :name => 'My Name',
    :email => 'my@name.com',
    '0' => {
      :name => 'Another Name',
      :email => 'another@name.com'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit hackish but you can do the following (not tested).  If you need them in an array, you can declare an instance variable outside the method and just use it in place of `puts v`

```
def get_email(hash)
  hash.each do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      get_email v
    elsif k.to_sym == :email
      puts v
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Monkeypatching the `Hash` class it’ll be like:

```
class Hash
  def find_all key  
    self.map { |k, v|
      v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.find_all(key) : (v if k.to_sym == key.to_sym) 
    }.flatten.compact    
  end  
end  
# ⇒ nil

> params.find_all :email
# ⇒ [
#  [0] "foo@bar.com",
#  [1] "my@name.com",
#  [2] "another@name.com"
# ]
```